# Expansion of a determinant in powers of $\lambda$ (from Courant-Hilbert Vol I)

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

On page 20-21 of volume I of Courant & Hilbert's "Methods of Mathematical Physics" they say:

> If we expand the determinants $\Delta(u,y;\lambda)$ and $\Delta(\lambda)$ in powers of $\lambda$, we obtain the expressions: $$\Delta(u,y;\lambda)= \Delta_1(u,y)-\lambda\Delta_2(u,y)+\lambda^2\Delta_2(u,y)-\ldots +(-1)^n\lambda^{n-1}\Delta_n(u,y),$$ $$\Delta(\lambda)=1-\lambda\Delta_1+\lambda^2\Delta_2-\ldots + (-1)^n \lambda^n \Delta_n,$$ where $$\begin{align*}
> \Delta_h(u,y)
> &= \sum
> \begin{vmatrix}
> 0 & u_{p_1} & \cdots & u_{p_h} \\ 
> y_{p_1} & t_{p_1p_1} & \cdots & t_{p_1p_h} \\
> \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
> y_{p_h} & t_{p_hp_1} & \cdots & t_{p_hp_h} \\ 
> \end{vmatrix}\\
> \end{align*}$$ and $$\begin{align*}
> \Delta_h 
> &= \sum
> \begin{vmatrix}
> t_{p_1p_1} & t_{p_1p_2} & \cdots & t_{p_1p_h} \\ 
> t_{p_2p_1} & t_{p_2p_2} & \cdots & t_{p_2p_h} \\
> \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\
> t_{p_hp_1} & t_{p_hp_2} & \cdots & t_{p_hp_h} \\ 
> \end{vmatrix}\\
> \end{align*}.  $$ The summations here are extended over all integers $p_1,p_2,\ldots , p_h$ from $1$ to $n$ with $p_1<p_2<\ldots < p_h$.

Where:

$$\begin{align*}
\Delta(u,y;\lambda)
&= 
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & u_1 & \cdots & u_n \\ 
y_1 & 1-\lambda t_{11} & \cdots & -\lambda t_{1n} \\
\vdots & \vdots &  \ddots &\vdots \\
y_n & -\lambda t_{n1} & \cdots & 1-\lambda t_{nn} \\ 
\end{vmatrix}\\
\end{align*}$$
and 
$$\begin{align*}
\Delta(\lambda) 
&= 
\begin{vmatrix}
1-\lambda t_{11} & -\lambda t_{12} & \cdots & -\lambda t_{1n} \\ 
-\lambda t_{21} & 1-\lambda t_{22} & \cdots & -\lambda t_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\
-\lambda t_{n1} & -\lambda t_{n2} & \cdots & 1-\lambda t_{nn} \\ 
\end{vmatrix}\\
\end{align*} $$

How to prove these two identities? with and without induction?

Comment: First, the book's name is "Courant&Hilbert", not the other way around. This is important in general, in particular in your case as: two,  you didn't even bother to give the name of the book, which is "Methods of Mathematical Physics" .

Comment: Are there more books that they coauthored?

Comment: @Ma I've no idea, but if you mention a book then I think it is worthwhile to be a little more careful and write the name(s) of the authors as they appear (most probably in alphabetical order) *and the name of the book*. People don't need to guess whether there's one single book by this or that author and its name, in my opinion.

Comment: @Joanpemo I edited my original post and added the name of the title of the book I am adressing my question to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will consider the simpler case of $\Delta(\lambda)$, but the approach should work for $\Delta(u,y;\lambda)$ as well. First, note that this determinant can be written in terms of column vectors as $$\Delta(\lambda)=\det(e_1-\lambda t_1,e_2-\lambda t_2,\cdots,e_n-\lambda t_n)$$
where $e_k$ is the $k$th basis column vector and $t_k=(t_{1k},t_{2k},\cdots,t_{nk})^T$. Since the determinant is a multilinear function of its column vectors, we have

\begin{align}
\Delta(\lambda)
=\det(e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_n)
&-\lambda\left[\det(t_1,e_2,\cdots,e_n)+\cdots+\det(e_1,e_2,\cdots,t_n)\right]\\
&+\lambda^2\left[\det(t_1,t_2,\cdots,e_n)+\cdots+\det(e_1,e_2,\cdots,t_{n-1},t_n)\right]\\
&-\cdots+(-\lambda)^n \det(t_1,t_2,\cdots,t_n).
\end{align}
All that remains is to identify each coefficient in this expansion with $\Delta_n$; this can be shown by taking each determinant and successively expanding-by-cofactors along any column containing $e_k$.

Comment: What is Laplace expanding?

Comment: [Laplace expansion = expansion by cofactors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion). I think I'll use the latter phrase instead, though. (Reading that Wiki page, I suspect what I should probably referencing is the more general notion of 'expansion by complementary minors.') @MathematicalPhysicist